# ARM bare-metal with MMU: write to non-cachable,non-bufferable mapped area fail

Tags: arm, buffer, cpu-cache, mmu, ioremap

I am ARM Cortex A9 CPU with 2 cores. But I just use 1 core and the other is just in a busy loop. I setup the MMU table using section (1MB per entry) like this:

```
0x00000000-0x14ffffff => 0x00000000-0x14ffffff (non-cachable, non-bufferable)
0x15000000-0x24ffffff => 0x15000000-0x24ffffff (cachable, bufferable)
0x25000000-0x94ffffff => 0x25000000-0x94ffffff (non-cachable, non-bufferable)
0x15000000-0x24ffffff => 0x95000000-0xa4ffffff (non-cachable, non-bufferable)
0xa5000000-0xffffffff => 0xa5000000-0xffffffff (non-cachable, non-bufferable)
```

It is rather simple. I just want to have a mirror of 256MB memory for non-cachable access. However, when I do several write to the the non-cachable memory section at 0x95000000-0xa4ffffff. I find the write is not actually written until I explicitly give a cache flush.

Am I doing something wrong or this kind of mapping is not valid? If that is the case, I don't understand how Linux's ioremap will be working on ARM. It will be good if anyone can give some explanation to me. Thanks very much.

Comment: you have 0x15000000 mapped to two different places?  How did you manage that?

Comment: @dwelch: I'm guessing left-hand side is physical addresses.

Comment: How do you know the write doesn't happen before a cache flush? I'm going to take a stab in the dark but are you writing to `0x95000000` but reading from `0x15000000` (which may have stale data in the cache)?

Comment: Am I doing something wrong?  You need to show us what you did, post code or mmu table settings, etc.  The problem may or may not be obvious from those details.

Comment: *I find the write is not actually written until I explicitly give a cache flush.* - How do you determine this?  By reading at 0x15000000-0x24ffffff?  This area maybe read-cached.  The cache is VIVT, it has no way of knowing about your aliasing.  Linux `ioremap()` will only allocate non-cacheable/non-bufferable, it doesn't map two sections/pages.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, left side is physical and right side is virtual. I am doing this because I have a device which will take an address of a data structure to start DMA the memory content to another device. Before the DMA is ticked start, I need to read and write to specify member of the structure. I find it is very inefficient to do cache invalidate and flush whenever I need to access 4 bytes of a structure. This is the reason why I want to have a uncached and unbuffer copy of memory. If this is not a proper to do this, is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: the Cortex-A9 is an ARMv7-A processor. The terms non-cacheable/non-bufferable/cacheable/bufferable are no longer correct descriptions of the mappings.
The actual mapping type is determined by TEX[2:0], C and B bits.

So I am actually having to guess a bit here as to what your mappings actually are.
And my guess is that you have the majority of your mappings set as Strongly-ordered, and the mirrored region as Normal Write-Back cacheable.

Having multiple virtual mappings with different memory types pointing to the same physical location is generally not a good idea in the ARM architecture. It used to be explicitly banned, but the latest version of the ARMv7-AR Architecture reference manual (DDI 0406C.b) has a (fairly long) section dedicated to the implications of "Mismatched memory attributes".

I would recommend finding a different way of achieving your goal.

Simply changing the mapping of the uncached regions to Normal Non-cacheable would be a good start. There is no valid reason for using Strongly-ordered mappings for RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, could you give me more details on how to do the changes? Thanks.